# How to append a div inside svg with javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I am trying to figure out how can I use `javascript` to generate the following `svg` programmatically.

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <rect class="bg" id="bg" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" fill="#0357D5"></rect>
    <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="60" height="50">
        <div xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">Thanks </div>
    </foreignObject>
</svg>
```

This is what I tried

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("svg");

const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

let bg = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
bg.setAttribute('class', 'bg');
bg.setAttribute('id', 'bg');  
bg.setAttribute('x',"0");
bg.setAttribute("y","0"); 
bg.setAttribute("width", "200");
bg.setAttribute("height", '200');
bg.setAttribute("fill","#0357D5");
svg.appendChild(bg); 

let fo = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'foreignObject');
fo.setAttribute("x", "0");
fo.setAttribute("y", "0");
fo.setAttribute("width", "60");
fo.setAttribute("height", "50");
svg.appendChild(fo);   

let _div = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'div');
_div.setAttribute("xmlns", 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');
_div.textContent = 'Thanks';
svg.appendChild(_div);
fo.appendChild(_div);
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
```

Comment: What is wrong? As far as I can see that SVG is generated when taking a look into the inspector

Comment: Javascript is generating the `div` but it is not visible on the `svg`, like the word `Thanks` is visible in the upper svg but not in the lower one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `createElement('div')` – not `createElementNS`, since its not an svg element.

```js
const svg = document.querySelector("#svg");

const svgns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";

let bg = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'rect');
bg.setAttribute('class', 'bg');
bg.setAttribute('id', 'bg');  
bg.setAttribute('x',"0");
bg.setAttribute("y","0"); 
bg.setAttribute("width", "200");
bg.setAttribute("height", '200');
bg.setAttribute("fill","#0357D5");
svg.appendChild(bg); 


let fo = document.createElementNS(svgns, 'foreignObject');
fo.setAttribute("x", "0");
fo.setAttribute("y", "0");
fo.setAttribute("width", "60");
fo.setAttribute("height", "50");
svg.appendChild(fo);   

let _div = document.createElement('div');
_div.setAttribute("xmlns", 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');
_div.textContent = 'Thanks';
svg.appendChild(_div);
fo.appendChild(_div);
```

```css
svg{
  display:inline-block;
  width:20em;
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="0 0 200 200" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks. This is awesome !!! completely forgot that `div` is not a `svg` element.